# Palindrome without using extra space

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I know various ways to check if an **integer** is a **palindrome** or not by using **string conversion, stack and number breaking**, but here question is 
"How can we check wether an **integer** is a **palindrome** or not, **without**  **using**    **any**  **extra**  **space**?"

Comment: http://www.leetcode.com/2012/01/palindrome-number.html

Comment: unable to think asked bymy classmate don't know the source.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert a number with some code like:

```
int revert(int num) {
  int reverted = 0;
  while (num) {
    reverted = reverted*10 + num%10;
    num /= 10;
  }
  return reverted;
}
```

And now you only check if

> num == revert(num)

That is all. Sorry for giving the exact solution instead of just a tip, but I don't think I could have given any tip without the solution itself.

Comment: -1 what if the number is negative? What if the reverted number overflows `int`?

Comment: I have read one same solution but I want to ask that int reverted is considered as extra space or not??

Comment: A negative number can not be palindrome. The problem statement states "integer" which I assumed is the type integer. If the number overflows integer, then the algorithm still will stay the same just a different type will be used. I think these remarks are not constructive. Sorry.

Comment: "A negative number can not be palindrome" yet you don't check whether the input is negative. "then the algorithm still will stay the same just a different type will be used" what if it overflows the other type as well. Any remark that proves the algorithm wrong is constructive. Think about it - for half the cases (negative `int`), your method doesn't work. Check the link I posted as a comment - much better ways exist.

Comment: See this - http://ideone.com/t2Nes

Comment: @L.ppt - no this solution uses constant additional memory(for 1 variable) and thus should be OK. I think what they mean is that you need to avoid converting to string. This solution is valid as I understand the statement.

Comment: I presume you mean "reverse", not "revert". And what is the reverse of 123000? How about 1230, or 123?

Comment: @NickJohnson agreed on both points. Still my code will never claim that 31300 is a palindrome so for the uses in this problem we should be ok.

Comment: Arguably, it is - it's equivalent to 0031300.